# Farseer physics not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, farseer

I have just started to port a load of projects from FPE2.x to FPE 3.3.1 and i am having some problems with all my physics.

This is a sample of what i am doing which demonstrates my problem

http://pastebin.com/wNfPhJUT

I can't workout what i'm doing wrong

Comment: It is impossible to know what's wrong. What is the problem? Where is the method `ApplyLinearImpulse`? Is this where you having the problem?

Comment: if you run the code you will see all the objects shaking as soon as they collide, also the ApplyLinearImpulse is not working (by that i mean there appears to be no impulse applied to the body). i would guess someone who has used farseer would be able to identify the problem by looking at the way ive set up the bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the sizes of the objects, in FPE2.x it would easily handle very large objects (i.e. 100 x 100) but in FPE 3.x they need to be a lot smaller (i.e. 0.1 x 0.1)